# mmenu - plugin: How to change the check button color?

Tags: css, mmenu

I want them to be more clear, I overwritten some default values with no luck.

```
.mm-menu label.mm-check:before {
  border-color: rgba(235, 255, 237, 1.0) !important; }
```

They're barely noticeable in smartphones.
I could set another values in this way (overwriting them) and they worked perfectly. I appreciate any suggestion about how to tweak it.
Thanks

Just in case bicimapuy.herokuapp.com

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the mmenu plugin. I believe you'll have to override the appropriate SASS variable to change the colour. The reason the colour isn't coming out correctly is because it's built in to show the  at 0.1 opacity.

Have a look at http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/custom-css/override-variables.html to work out how to do it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of that, but for a matter of time I preferred to do a shorcut. The weird thing is I could change the toggle button colour and its size by overriding them with !important.

Comment: I forgot to mention I can change the color, but it isn't to get it more clear than that.

Comment: Besides this variable isn't in the list..http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/custom-css/override-variables.html so I don't know if sass would help

Comment: Try
    .mm-menu label.mm-check:before{
       border-color: rgba(235, 255, 237, 1.0) !important;
       opacity: 0.4 !important;
    }

You can change the opacity to make the colour stronger or weaker.

Comment: I got closer, but when I check the check button, the color doesn't change. It isn't possible to distinguish if it was selected or not
I tryed with

.mm-menu label.mm-check:after --or with check property, but it isn't working. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Well this is the solution, hope it helps anyone else

```
/* default state */
label.mm-check:before {
   border-color: blue !important;
   opacity: 1 !important;
}

/* checked state */
input.mm-check:checked ~ label.mm-check:before {
   border-color: pink !important;
   opacity: 1 !important;
}
```